# How do I allow a c# process to create a file as if it were run on the command line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to execute a process exactly as if it were executed on the window's command line but the process class won't allow the executable to create a file similar to what it would do if it were run from the command line. The Processes will when deployed run asynchronously on a server at timed intervals. The command line would calls would look like this:

curl.exe url -o data

wgrib2.exe data -csv output.csv

In the code below I found a workaround for curl.exe but when it is read as StandardOutput the file cuts off some of the critical stopping characters for this file type.

```
public static void httpQuery(string queryString)
{
    Process myProcess = new Process();
    try
    {
        string basepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;            // allows us to redirect the output
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;              // stop's command window from being made
        myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Ian's\Desktop\wgrib2\curl.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = queryString;            // queryString is http://nomads.noaa.gov/....
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;       // redirect error to stream reader
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;      // redirect output to strem reader

        myProcess.Start();
        if (myProcess.WaitForExit(10000) == false)
        {
            myProcess.Kill();
        }
        using(StreamReader reader = myProcess.StandardError)    // capture error output if any
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();                 
            reader.Close();
            StreamReader message = myProcess.StandardOutput;
            string output = message.ReadToEnd();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(basepath + "wgrib2\\data");
            writer.Write(output);
            writer.Close();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    myProcess.Close();
}
```

Additionally, I cannot seem to find a way to allow the second process to write a new file, or if it has been I cannot find the directory that it is writing to. I am working with VS2012 on the IIS development server. This is the second processes code.

```
public static void callWgrib2()
    {
        Process wgrib2 = new Process();
        try
        {
            // call on command line: wgrib2.exe data -csv data.csv

            string basepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;            // path to project directory
            string arg1 = basepath + "wgrib2\\data";                            // filename of operate on
            string arg2 =" -csv " + basepath + "wgrib2\\data.csv";              // filename to write to

            wgrib2.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;                           // parameters
            wgrib2.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            wgrib2.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            wgrib2.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Ian's\Desktop\wgrib2\wgrib2.exe";
            wgrib2.StartInfo.Arguments = "\""+ arg1 + arg2 + "\"";
            wgrib2.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            wgrib2.Start();

            if (wgrib2.WaitForExit(10000) == false)
            {
                wgrib2.Kill();
            }
            using (StreamReader reader = wgrib2.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                StreamReader err = wgrib2.StandardError;
                err.ReadToEnd();
                err.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        wgrib2.Close();
    }
```

Can someone point me in the write direction I have put considerable effort into this problem but I'm sure there exits a simple workaround I'm not aware of.

Comment: Use `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: I agree with Slaks: why would you bother using curl.exe in the first place?  C# ships with objects fully capable of connecting to and grabbing information from a url.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the actual command line process, you can use `cmd` and pass the `/c` flag to it in the arguements

also, the line

```
wgrib2.StartInfo.Arguments = "\""+ arg1 + arg2 + "\"";
```

looks odd

do you really need all your arguments such as `-csv` to be in the same quotes block?

it's like calling on the command line

```
C:\Users\Ian's\Desktop\wgrib2\wgrib2.exe "c:\base\wgrib2\data -csv c:\base\wgrib2\data.csv"
```